# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass using RoR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error in my login form when i am trying to attempt by putting the wrong data which should usually shows the login failed message.

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Sessions#loginadmin

Showing C:/Site/swargadwar_admin/app/views/homes/index.html.erb where line #71 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #71):

68:                                 <% end %>
69:                         </div>
70:                         <div class="error-div">
71:                                     <% if @admin.errors.any? %>
72:                                       <div id="error_explanation">
73:                                       <h2><%= pluralize(@admin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
74:
```

Please check my codes below and let me to know where i am doing the mistake.

## views/homes/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="text-align:center;"><img src="/assets/admin.png" style="width:100px; height:120px; " /></div>
    <div class="text-div" style="text-align:center;">Swargadwar, Puri Municipality,govt of odisha</div>
            <section>
            <% if !current_user %>              
                <div id="container_demo" >
                    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                            <%= form_for :admin,:url => {:action =>'loginadmin',:controller => 'sessions' } do |f| %>
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                     <%= f.email_field :email,placeholder:"mysupermail@mail.com",:id => "username" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                     <%= f.password_field :password,placeholder:"eg. X8df!90EO",:id => "password" %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <%= f.check_box :remember_me,:id => "loginkeeping" %>
                                                   <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                 <%= link_to 'Forgetting password ?',admins_forget_path %>
                                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <%= f.submit "Login" %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
                                    Not a member yet ?
                                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                                <% end %>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div id="register" class="animate form">
                            <%= form_for :admin,:url => {:action => 'create_registration',:controller => "admins" } do |f| %>
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                    <%= f.text_field :user_name,placeholder:"mysuperusername690",:id => "usernamesignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                     <%= f.email_field :email,placeholder:"mysupermail@mail.com",:id => "emailsignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <%= f.password_field :password,placeholder:"eg. X8df!90EO",:id => "passwordsignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,placeholder:"eg. X8df!90EO",:id => "passwordsignup" %>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                     <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Add Image</label>
                                     <%= f.file_field :picture %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button">
                                <%= f.submit "Sign Up"%> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">  
                                    Already a member ?
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                                <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="error-div">
                                    <% if @admin.errors.any? %>
                                      <div id="error_explanation">
                                      <h2><%= pluralize(@admin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

                                      <ul>
                                      <% @admin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                     <li><%= msg %></li>
                                     <% end %>
                                     </ul>
                                    </div>
                                  <% end %>
                               </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                 <% end %> 
            </section>
        </div>
```

## controller/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def loginadmin
        @admin=Admin.authenticate(params[:admin][:email], params[:admin][:password])
        if @admin
            session[:user_id]=@admin.id
            cookies.signed[:user_id]=@admin.id
            params[:admin][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@admin) : forget(@admin)
            flash[:notice]="Login Successfull"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "new", :controller => "admins"
        else
            flash[:notice]="Login Failed"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'homes/index'
        end
    end
    def removeuser
        session[:user_id] = nil
        cookies.delete :user_id
        flash[:notice]="user logged out successfully"
        flash[:color]="valid"
        redirect_to :action => 'index', :controller => 'homes'
    end
end
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @admin=Admin.new
    end
end
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: you render `index.html` in `loginadmin` with `@admin == nil` (`else` clause)

Comment: @Victor Moroz ,If user will insert wrong data it will show failed message in the same login page(i.e-index.html).So whats the solution for this.

Comment: `@admin && @admin.errors.any?` ? What error message are you supposed to show for `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explanatory.

> NoMethodError in Sessions#loginadmin
>
> undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

*You are getting this error because **@admin is nil** and you are **calling errors method on a nil object.***.

If you look loginadmin action is sessions controller *you are rendering 'index' template when there is no @admin object, which is causing this error.*

**Fix:**

Either create separate templates for both these actions with common code in partials or simply use rails [`try method`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) which *returns nil rather than raising an exception*

```
<% if @admin.try(:errors).try(:any?) %>
```

OR

Just use a condition at top to separate out error code:

```
<% if @admin %>
  <div class="error-div">
    <% if @admin.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@admin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @admin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**P.S *I would recommend you to use different templates with common code separated in partials.***

Comment: @user4703663 yeah you can but error is related to admin being nil and rest will show up only when there are any errors so why use extra condition when you can do it with one. :)